# In-line replacement bash (replace line with new one using variables)

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed, awk

I'm going through and reading lines from a file. They have a ton of information that is unnecessary, and I want to reformat the lines for later use so that I can use the necessary information later.

Example line in file (file1)

```
Name: *name* Date: *date* Age: *age* Gender: *gender* Score: *score*
```

Say I want to just pull gender and age from the file and use that later

New line

```
*gender*, *age*
```

In bash:

```
    while read line; do
       <store variable for gender>
       <store variable for age>
     <overwrite each line in CSV - gender,age>
     <use gender/age as inputs for later comparisons>  
     done < file1
```

EDIT: There is no stability in the entries. One value can be found using a `echo $line | cut` and the other value is found using a `[ $line =~ "keyValue" ]` then setting that value

I was thinking of storing the combination of the two variables as such:

```
newLine="$val1,$val2"
```

Then using a sed in-line replace to replace the `$line` with `$newLine`.

Is there a better way, though? It may come down to a sed formatting issue with variables.

Comment: Is the sequence of entries stable?  Are all the entries guaranteed to appear in every line? If they're not all guaranteed to appear, what to do with lines with Age but no Gender, or Gender but no Age?  Presumably, lines with neither Age nor Gender would be ignored?

Comment: What do you mean by *"use gender/age as inputs for later comparisons"*? Also, mind showing an example line in your CSV file? And are you not needing the name as reference to replace the target gender/age? Is the information in the CSV file only about one person? The values like `name` and `date` do have spaces on them right? P.S. It's easier to process CSV files with Ruby.

Comment: Can `*name*` (or any other field) contain spaces? Can it contain colons? You mention CSV but I don't see any commas in your input - does your posted input line REALLY represent your actual input? Post a few lines of actual sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will produce your desired output from your posted sample input:

```
$ cat file
Name: *name* Date: *date* Age: *age* Gender: *gender* Score: *score*

$ awk -F'[: ]+' -v OFS=', ' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) a[$i]=$(i+1); print a["Gender"], a["Age"]}' file
*gender*, *age*

$ awk -F'[: ]+' -v OFS=', ' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) a[$i]=$(i+1); print a["Score"], a["Name"], a["Date"] }' file
*score*, *name*, *date*
```

and you can see above how easy it is to print whatever fields you like in whatever order you like.

If it's not what you want, post some more representative input.

Answer (score 2):

Your example leaves room for interpretation, so I'm assuming that there may be whitespace in the field values, but that there are no colons in the field values and that each field key is followed by a colon. I also assume that the order is stable.

```
while IFS=: read _ _ _ age gender _; do
    age="${age% Gender}" # Use parameter expansion to strip off the key for the *next* field.
    gender="${gender% Score}"
    printf '"%s","%s"\n' "$gender" "$age"
done < file1 > file1.csv
```

#### Update

Since your question now states that there is no stability, you have to iterate through the possible values to get your output:

```
while IFS=: read -a line; do
    unset age key sex
    for chunk in "${line[@]}"; do
        val="${chunk% *}" # Everything but the key
        case "$key" in
            Age) age="$val";;
            Gender) sex="$val";;
        esac
        # The key is for the *next* iteration.
        key="${chunk##* }"
    done
    if [[ $age || $sex ]]; then
        printf '"%s","%s"\n' "$sex" "$age"
    fi
done < file1 > file1.csv
```

(Also I added quotes around the output values in the csv to be compliant with the actual csv format and in case sex or age happened to have commas in it. Maybe someone is 1,000,000 years old. ;)

Comment: Good grief. This is why you don't use shell to parse text files - use the right tool for the job, i.e. awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Would you like to suggest an actual improvement I could apply? The shell is quite often an *excellent* way to reformat text, so I object to your underspecified objection.

Comment: I did suggest an improvement - use the tool that was invented to manipulate text, has all of the builtin constructs needed to simplify the manipulation of text, and is available on all UNIX installations, i.e. awk. Not sure what else I could do to be more specific.

Comment: @EdMorton Mostly your comment is just awk flag-waving, but that's not necessary because your answer ought to stand by itself. Your comment could be more constructive if you would point out what it is that you think is so broken about my solution that it exemplifies why you shouldn't use the shell to parse text files.

Comment: I assumed the issues were self-evident. If not, I apologize. Here are some of the common issues with parsing text files with shell scripts which are exemplified by that script: it is lengthy, complex, and data-coupled to the input (see use of specific "key" values as variables and cases in the shell script).